# Why is my CC INT3 instruction not doing anything when I single-step my buffer overflow in GDB?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow

I am doing protostar exploit exercises # 5.

Basically this is the code and the goal is to redirect code execution to your shellcode. My question just involves why my instructions are not executing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[64];

  gets(buffer);
}
```

This is a buffer overflow question. I have successfully redirected the return address to the beginning of my nop sled followed by the int3 "\xcc" shellcode that stops the program from executing (just to check if it'll execute)

```
"\x90\x90\x90\x90\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc"
```

Essentially as I step through my nop sled it just says

```
0xbffff7a2 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0xbffff7a3 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0xbffff7a4 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Keep in mind I redirected code execution successfully to these addresses, and I inspected these addresses to be     "\x90"s and "\xcc"s respectively. But nothing happens. The program didn't even receive an interrupt from the "\xcc"'s.

I might have not given enough information, but essentially it should be executing these instructions, but it seems not.

I imagine it could be that the instructions need to be byte aligned? But does that even matter?

I would just like to know what are some reasons why instructions may not execute even tho you are pointing right on that address.

```
This is x86 Architecture machine.
```

Comment: Use `layout reg` to see a disassembly window as you `stepi`, instead of just code addresses with `??`.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB tips.

Comment: Ok thank you! I realize that  `stepi` i will not execute the interrupt. I had to use `continue` to see it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gdb is using int3 internally that's why you see no effect. 
You should tell it to ignore SIGTRAP signal and pass it to the process instead.

```
(gdb) handle SIGTRAP nostop noprint pass
SIGTRAP is used by the debugger.
Are you sure you want to change it? (y or n) y

Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGTRAP       No        No      Yes             Trace/breakpoint trap

(gdb) si

Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
The program no longer exists.
```

Since you are trying to use this only for detecting code execution in user mode, consider using some other instruction that will cause a fault, for example `HLT`. That won't interfere with debugger operation so you don't need to change the signal handling.